# How do I flatten an array of arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have an array consisting of following elements:

```
var schools = new [] {
    new object[]{ new[]{ "1","2" }, "3","4" },
    new object[]{ new[]{ "5","6" }, "7","8" },
    new object[]{ new[]{ "9","10","11" }, "12","13" }
};
```

The real object that i try to flatten is from importing data into array of arrays from CSV and then joining it on values of fields:

```
    var q =
        from c in list
        join p in vocatives on c.Line[name1].ToUpper() equals p.first_name.ToUpper() into ps
        from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new object[] { c.Line,  p == null ? "(No vocative)" : p.vocative, p == null ? "(No sex)" : p.sex };
```

I want to flatten that array of strings to get:

```
string[] {
    new string[]{ "1","2","3","4" },
    new string[]{ "5","6","7","8" },
    new string[]{ "9","10","11","12","13" }
}
```

I already have an solution that does that in loop, its not so performance-wise, but it seems to work ok.

I've tried to use `SelectMany` but cannot make up a solution.

Thank you very much for feedback ;)
I've tried answer from npo:

```
var result = schools.Select(z => z.SelectMany(y=> y.GetType().IsArray 
           ? (object[])y : new object[] { y })
);
```

But CSVwriter class method accepts only explicitly typed:

```
IEnumerable<string[]>
```

So how to do it in linq, I've tried to:

```
List<string[]> listOflists = (List<string[]>)result;
```

But no go, `InvalidCastException` arrises, unfortunately.

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem.

Comment: Because you are mixing arrays of strings with strings I don't think there is going to be an easy linq solution. I think you'll need to do a more traditional loop checking if each item is an array or a string and dealing with it based on that check.

Comment: "I've tried to use SelectMany" Then show what you´ve tried please. I doubt it´ll help you if anyone here comes to the exact same solution you already have and posts it here.

Comment: One thing: I note in your examples that there is always one string array and it is always the first item in the object array. Is that a rule or is that just coincidence in your test data?

Comment: If this kind of structure is generated "naturally" by your application or data (i.e. not a puzzle or homework exercise), consider reworking it. While you can write code to process it (as the answers show) part of the difficulty is that this kind of structure is rather poorly typed as far as O-O is concerned. For example, if single strings were represented as one-element arrays, the whole thing would fit naturally in a `string[][][]`. Alternatively, proper classes that encapsulate the data that those strings represent would also help (`string Value` and `string[] Children`, for example).

Comment: this is for converting csv data imported to array, and joining it with another list:

`var q =
            from c in lista
            join p in vocatives on c.Line[imie1].ToUpper() equals p.first_name.ToUpper() into ps
            from p in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new object[] { c.Line,  p == null ? "(No products)" : p.vocative, p == null ? "(No products)" : p.sex };` I need this data to be an array of arrays :)

Comment: @Chris no, its not a coincidence, check my edit to deduce from where i get the object :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a first step, you have to normalize the data to one kind of type. Then you can iterate over them as you like. So at first create a method to flatten the values from a specific point to an arbitrary depth:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<object> FlattenArrays(this IEnumerable source)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (item is IEnumerable inner
                && !(item is string))
            {
                foreach (var innerItem in inner.FlattenArrays())
                {
                    yield return innerItem;
                }
            }

            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can either iterate on the top level to get a single array of all values:

```
// Produces one array => ["1", "2", "3", "4", ...]
var allFlat = schools.FlattenArrays().OfType<string>().ToArray();
```

Or you can create individual array one depth deeper:

```
foreach (var item in schools)
{
    // Produces an array for each top level e.g. ["5", "6", "7", "8"]
    var flat = item.FlattenArrays().OfType<string>().ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the comments, because your inner array mixes elements of `string[]` and `string`, it likely won't be trivial to do this directly in Linq.

However, with the assistance of a helper function (I've called `Flattener`) you can branch the handling of both of the inner types manually to either return the elements in the array (if it's `string[]`), or to return the single element as an enumerable, if it's not. `SelectMany` can then be used to flatten the inner level, but the outer level seemingly you want to leave unflattened:

i.e.

```
var schools = new [] {
    new object[]{new[]{"1","2"}, "3","4"}, 
    new object[]{new[]{"5","6"}, "7","8"},
    new object[]{new[]{"9","10","11"}, "12","13"}
};

var result = schools
    .Select(s => s.SelectMany(o => Flattener(o)));
```

Which returns a type of `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`

Where the messy unpacking bit done by:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Flattener(object o)
{
    if (o is IEnumerable<string> strings)
    {
        return strings;
    }
    if (o is string s)
    {
       return new[]{s};
    }
    return new[]{"?"};
}
```

Note the above uses the pattern matching capabilities of C#7.

Result screenshot courtesy of LinqPad:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want o do it via linq here is a sample

```
     var schools = new[] {
    new object[]{new[]{"1","2"}, "3","4"},
    new object[]{new[]{"5","6"}, "7","8"},
    new object[]{new[]{"9","10","11"}, "12","13"}
};

var result = schools.Select(z => z.SelectMany(y=> y.GetType().IsArray ? (object[])y : new object[] { y }));
```

Comment: Proof that just because it can be done in LINQ doesn't mean it has to be done in LINQ. Nicely figured out though.

Comment: Note that casting an array to `object[]` only works if the array is of reference type. `int[]` cannot be converted to `object[]`. A more general solution would be `... y=> y is IEnumerable ? ((IEnumerable)y).Cast<object>() : new object[] { y }` However, be careful; `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so you might want a test for string-ness in there!

Answer (score 0):

The presented solution is devoted to convert any sort of `int` array, *regular, jagged, *or* nested* (*these last are taken from javascript and its  object notation, but they can also be implemented as complex jagged array of objects in C#*), into a simple mono-dimensional integers array.

To adapt your request to it, you should have only change the `string` type elements of your objects jagged array into `int` type.

Here it is the C# function:

```
    public static int[] getFlattenedIntArray(object jaggedArray)
    {

        var flattenedArray = new List<int>();

        var jaggedArrayType = jaggedArray.GetType();
        var expectedType = typeof(int);

        if (jaggedArrayType.IsArray)
        {
            if (expectedType.IsAssignableFrom(jaggedArrayType.GetElementType()))
            {
                foreach (var el in jaggedArray as int[])
                {
                    flattenedArray.Add(el);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var el in jaggedArray as object[])
                {
                    foreach (var retIntEl in getFlattenedIntArray(el))
                    {
                        flattenedArray.Add(retIntEl);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        else if (jaggedArrayType == expectedType)
        {
            flattenedArray.Add((int)jaggedArray);
        }
        else
        {
            return new int[0];
        }

        return flattenedArray.ToArray();
    }
```

Try it in this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5HGX96